# Wave transmission in underwater slope

Tags: waves, reflection, tsunami

A typical tsunami has wavelengths comparable to continental slopes. So surely reflection plays a significant role in determining runup.

So consider a wave of small amplitude A1 and wavelength l1 ascending from d1 to d2 across a plane of length L.

What is the equation that relates new amplitude A2 to the above?

Answer (score 0):

See the book by Horillo, Knight, and Kowalik, *Numerical Modeling Of Tsunami Waves* (advanced series on ocean engineering, volume 54). Be warned it is *very* heavy on advanced math.

Comment: Oops, I asked the wrong question. See if you can answer the right one now. Thsnks